# Change default landing page on StackApps

Tags: feature-request, stackapps

With the release of the 1.1 API (thanks, btw), StackApps has grown a default landing page that I really don't care about.  I go to StackApps to discuss the API, not see the list of libraries.  Frankly, I don't care about the libraries and apps, because I work on my own ([StackKit](https://stackapps.com/questions/346)).

As such, when I go to http://stackapps.com, I have to spend the extra time clicking from the "Apps" area to the "Active" area.  This is especially annoying when I click the "StackApps" logo.

Can there be a way for me to say "my default landing page is 'Active' and not 'Apps'"?

Comment: +1 this is much needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [Greasemonkey script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2058/make-active-tab-default-on-stackapps) to accomplish this.

Comment: +1 cool, I've never used greasemonkey before, but this is pretty neat.  I suppose a SafariExtension could probably do the same thing.

Comment: @Dave: Actually, it's possible to install GreaseMonkey scripts in Safari by using GreaseKit.

Comment: @George yeah, some googling revealed that. I decided to try the extension approach since it's the native solution for my browser. (I did install GreaseKit, and Simon's script works perfectly, but I prefer the extension)

Answer (score 3):

In general the sites keep track of which tab you last visited, so that should be allowed for stackapps as well.

Until then, change your bookmark to https://stackapps.com/?tab=active and when you start typing "sta..." into your addressbar, you might have to press the down arrow a few more times to hit https://stackapps.com/?tab=active rather than https://stackapps.com/ (although if that's not appearing in your address bar history you may need to train it by manually entering https://stackapps.com/?tab=active a few times)

Comment: What if we're using Lynx?

Comment: @George Then you should be using the [Column 80](http://stackapps.com/questions/542/column-80-plain-text-optimised-sofu) stack exchange interface, and should request a similar feature there if it's still a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simon Brown's suggestion works, and if you use Safari, you could make an extension to do it (I'm a fan of native solutions):

1. Safari's Develop menu > Show Extension Builder
2. Add a new extension and change the name and identifier to something relevant
3. Open your editor of choice and create a new `.js` file in the `.safariextension` folder of your new extension
4. Put the following in the script, then save and close:

   ```
   var tab = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab();
   if (tab.url == "http://stackapps.com/") {
       tab.url = "http://stackapps.com/?tab=active";
   }
   ```
5. Back in the extension builder, click the "New Script" button next to "Start Scripts:"
6. From the menu that just showed up, choose the script you just created.
7. Click the "Install" button

Comment: You should check out NinjaKit—it's an Extension that adds GreaseMonkey functionality to Safari 5. Good stuff.